# Exitting a while(cin >> s) loop with a carriage return

Tags: c++

Is it possible to exit a loop `while(cin >> x)` where `x` is a `char` once the user hits *enter* instead of creating another error flag such as a punctuation or `EOF` - Ctrl + Z?

I am using `while(cin >> x)` instead of `cin` or `getline` because I want to read the characters one by one including white spaces.

Is there another way to read the character one by one and use the *enter* as a termination flag?

I tried using an `if` statement with `\r` and `\n` but it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: can you use a "signal or exit character" ?

Comment: @DavidKernin I can but I was searching for a way that doesn't need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just read a single character at a time and check them:

```
char x;
while (cin.get(x) && x != '\n') {
  // ...
```

You need to use `cin.get(x)` instead of `cin >> x` because you actually want to read whitespace characters like newline, which `operator >>` skips by default.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity what are the benefits of using cin.get(x) in a while loop versus cin>>x. Can one always use cin.get(x) for a char x or are there specific cases where the former is preferable?

Comment: The way I showed you gets a single character, with no fancy skipping of whitespace as `operator >>` does by default.   Since you are looking for whitespace, this seemed logical.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, could you please update the answer with that information on difference between cin >> x and cin.get(x), since the explanation is great and it might be very useful for the future readers.

Comment: I tried the same exact thing as you but with while (cin>>x && x != '\n'), but it didn't work. So, I am wondering why it failed with cin>>x. Does \n count as a whitespace? because when I tried cin>>noskipws>>s it worked.

Comment: @user29568, yep, '\n' is definitely a whitespace (that's why my answer did not work :))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getch, for example

```
c = null
 while(c != 0x0D) //0x0D for Carriage Return
 {
    c = getch();
 }
```

[More detail](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch)